# Sort an JSON array based on array values

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON array like this

```
$countries = [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "country_name": "Afghanistan",
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "country_name": "Albania",
        },
        {
          "id": "3",
          "country_name": "Algeria",
        },
        {
          "id": "4",
          "country_name": "American Samoa",
        }       
        ..
        ..
        ..
        {
          "id": "50",
          "country_name": "Zimbabwe",
        }
];
```

The following array contains, the list of countries that I need to sort to top

```
$top_countries = ['United States', 'United Kingdom', 'German'];
```

**What is the best way to sort the above array as follows**

```
$countries = [
        {
          "id": "30",
          "country_name": "United States",
        },
        {
          "id": "31",
          "country_name": "United Kingdom",
        },
        {
          "id": "20",
          "country_name": "German",
        },
        {
          "id": "1",
          "country_name": "Afghanistan",
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "country_name": "Albania",
        },
        {
          "id": "3",
          "country_name": "Algeria",
        },
        {
          "id": "4",
          "country_name": "American Samoa",
        }       
        ..
        ..
        ..
        {
          "id": "50",
          "country_name": "Zimbabwe",
        }
];
```

Comment: `json_decode()` + `uasort()` + `json_encode()`

Comment: Without decode, I don't think php support to sort json, So, Decode json and convert to array, make necessary sorting operations and then again convert it to json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// index "value" of country by name
$top = array_flip($top_countries);

usort($countries, function($a, $b) use ($top) {
    // get "value" for each country, if it is in index
    $aValue = isset($top[$a->country_name])?$top[$a->country_name]:-1;
    $bValue = isset($top[$b->country_name])?$top[$b->country_name]:-1;

    if ($aValue == $bValue) {
        // preserve "original order", assuming they were ordered by id 
        return $a->id < $b->id ? -1 : 1;
    }
    return $aValue < $bValue ? 1:-1;
});
```

Comment: Great! it works! Please update your answer that need to reverse the array before flip it. :)

Comment: Also, change $a->country_name to $a['country_name']

Comment: @Asik, I reverted 1 and -1 it in the return statement of the closure. It is cheaper than reverse `$top_countries`

Comment: Anyway, remaining countries orders are changed. I want to keep the remaining countries list order same.

Comment: Inverting order of original array won't help. I updated the answer to maintain order for  "non-top" countries.

Comment: Super! it works fine!!  return $a['country_name'] < $b['country_name'] ? -1 : 1;

Comment: yep, assuming they were sorted alphabetically is equally fair